# How to get a http long connection by django and requests?

Tags: python, django, http, tcp

Some articles said if the http server and http client both use Connection: keep-alive in there header, then the tcp connection will be a long connection.

So I did my test below.

Client code:

```
import requests
import time


url = 'http://server url'


def session_req(url):
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(url, headers={'Connection':'keep-alive'})
    print(r.headers)
    print(r.status_code)

    while True:
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    session_req(url=url)
```

From the client print we can see the server add **Connection: keep-alive** too

But the tcp connection still not a long connection.

```
# ss -tan
FIN-WAIT-2 0      0      server ip:8004               client ip:40238
```

As you can see the tcp is not established

So anything wrong about my code? How to make a long http connection?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to Django's development server? It is possible that it dones not support long connections.

Comment: @OzgurAkcali It is a uwsgi